# Uniformly convergence of $f_n(x) = \frac{(x + 1)^n}{1 + (x - 1)^n}$ $\forall x \in R\backslash\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Given $f_n(x) = \frac{(x + 1)^n}{1 + (x - 1)^n}$ I want to prove the uniformly convergence.

The succession of functions pointwise converges in $(-\infty,0)$.

Because $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f_n(x)=1$ there isn't uniformly convergence in

$(-\infty,0)$ because sup$_{(-\infty,0)}f_n(x)$ doesn't converge to zero.

But can I have uniformly convergence in $[a,b]\subset(-\infty,0)$?

Comment: Are you sure that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=1$? I am getting zero.

Comment: The limit is for $x\rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: Oh, that is...unusual to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in[a,b]$ for any fixed $[a,b]\subset(-\infty,0)$, Since
$$
0 \le \bigg| \frac{(x+1)^n}{1+(x-1)^n}\bigg| \le \bigg(\frac{|x+1|}{1-x}\bigg)^n
$$
and both functions tend to $0$ for any fixed $x$ as $n\to\infty$, it suffices to prove uniform convergence for the right-hand side. The function $|x+1|/(1-x)$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,-1)$ and increasing on $(-1,0)$, and therefore it is bounded above on $[a,b]$ by $c=\max\big\{ |a+1|/(1-a), |b+1|/(1-b) \big\} < 1$. Therefore for $x\in[a,b]$,
$$
0 \le \bigg| \frac{(x+1)^n}{1+(x-1)^n}\bigg| \le \bigg(\frac{|x+1|}{1-x}\bigg)^n \le c^n,
$$
which tends to $0$ uniformly for these $x$.